# Create a new column to differentiate categories of products

Tags: sql, case

I’m trying to create a new column called category by separating products into categories.

```
SELECT  price, productid, Products.Name

FROM Products

CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%frame%' THEN 'frame'

    WHEN Name LIKE '%mountain-%' THEN 'mountain'

    WHEN Name LIKE '%road-%' THEN 'road'

    WHEN Name LIKE '%touring-%' THEN 'touring'

      WHEN name LIKE '%socks%' OR '%vest%' OR '%jersey%' OR '%gloves%' OR '%shorts%' OR '%tights%' THEN 'apparel’

ELSE 'equipment'
END “Category”
```

I’ve tried changing like to = sign as well as removing WHEN name LIKE to  When

Comment: Is your `CASE` result supposed to be a new column?  If so, it should be before the `FROM` and it should have a column name.

Comment: Also, you can't just say `name like '%val1%' or '%val2%' or '%val3%'`. It needs to be `name like '%val1%' or name like '%val2%' or name like '%val2%'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as follows the `from` clause should be after the `case when`.

And `name LIKE '%socks%' OR '%vest% ... '` must be `name LIKE '%socks%' OR  name LIKE '%vest%' ...`  :

```
SELECT  price, productid, Products.Name,
CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%frame%' THEN 'frame'
     WHEN Name LIKE '%mountain-%' THEN 'mountain'
     WHEN Name LIKE '%road-%' THEN 'road'
     WHEN Name LIKE '%touring-%' THEN 'touring'
     WHEN name LIKE '%socks%' OR  name LIKE '%vest%' OR  name LIKE '%jersey%' OR  name LIKE '%gloves%' OR  name LIKE '%shorts%' OR  name LIKE '%tights%' THEN 'apparel'
     ELSE 'equipment'
END as 'Category'
FROM Products
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got your condition in the query filering section. See my example:

select
id,
topicid,
articlename,
case
when articlename like 'test%' then 'Test'
when articlename like 'prod%' then 'Published'
else 'Editing'
end category
from
articles